# tkinter, "refresh" the mainwindow

Tags: python, tkinter

Though I think that the solution might be similar to this one: [tkinter, display a value from subwindow in mainwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542255/tkinter-display-a-value-from-subwindow-in-mainwindow/33542456#33542456) , I still decided to ask this question since I have trouble to figure it out on my own.

I have the list "fields" with which I am creating any given number of rows, with two labes inside of them. After opening a subwindow, I want to be able to manipulate that list (in my example simply just append at the moment) and after clicking on a button (here "ADD"), I want the mainwindow to update, so that it shows the rows of the manipulated list. It works fine for the most part but I dont what is the best way to update the mainwindow in this example.

The only solution I was able to come up with, is to destroy the mainwindow and recreate it but I have the feeling that this might not be the best solution. Is there a better one?

```
import tkinter as tk

a=0
fields=[("a",1),("c",2),("e",3)]

class clsApp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root=tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("MainWindow")
        ##Labels##
        self.rootLabel=tk.Label(self.root, text="WindowAppExperiment", padx=100)
        self.aLabel=tk.Label(self.root, text=a, padx=100)
        ##Buttons##
        self.BtExit=tk.Button(self.root, text="Quit", fg="red", command=self.root.quit)
        ###self.BtNewWindow=tk.Button(self.root, text ="Edit", command=lambda:self.clsNewWindow(self.root, self.aLabel).run())
        self.BtNewField=tk.Button(self.root, text ="New Field", padx=30, command=lambda:self.clsNewFields(self.root).run())

    def grid (self):
        self.rootLabel.pack()
        self.aLabel.pack()
        self.fckPackFields()
        self.BtNewField.pack()
        self.BtExit.pack(side="left")
        ###self.BtNewWindow.pack(side="right")

    def fckPackFields(self):
        if fields:
            for field in fields:
                ##create labels##
                row=tk.Frame(self.root)
                nameLabel=tk.Label(row, text =field[0], width=20, anchor="w")
                valueLabel=tk.Label(row, text =field[1], width=5)
                ##pack labels##
                row.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)
                nameLabel.pack(side="left")
                valueLabel.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="x")


    def run(self):
        self.grid()
        self.root.mainloop()
        self.root.destroy()

    class clsNewFields(object):

        def __init__(self, Parent):
            self.parent=Parent
            ##Window##
            self.top=tk.Toplevel()
            self.top.title("Add Fields")
            ##Labels##
            self.enterNameLabel=tk.Label(self.top, text ="Enter fieldname", padx=10)
            self.enterValueLabel=tk.Label(self.top, text ="Enter value", padx=10)
            ##Entryfields##
            self.EntryName=tk.Entry(self.top)
            self.EntryValue=tk.Entry(self.top)
            ##Buttons##
            self.BtADD=tk.Button(self.top, text ="ADD", command=lambda:self.fckAddField(self.EntryName, self.EntryValue))
            self.BtClose=tk.Button(self.top, text ="Close", command=self.top. quit)

        def grid(self):
            self.enterNameLabel.pack()
            self.enterValueLabel.pack()
            self.EntryName.pack()
            self.EntryValue.pack()
            self.BtADD.pack()
            self.BtClose.pack()

        def fckAddField(self, Name, Value):
            self.name=Name.get()
            self.value=Value.get()
            global fields
            fields.append((self.name, self.value))
            print(fields)
            self.parent.update


        def run(self):
            self.grid()
            self.top.mainloop()
            self.top.destroy()



clsApp().run()
```

Comment: i believe you can use `main.update()` where `main` is your main window.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have it already there in the form: self.parent.update() . The one in this example is admittedly missing the "()" but I have tried that one out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

First of all - do you really want to declare the `clsNewFields` **inside** your `clsApp` ? Yes, the Fields should be used inside App, but i do not see a need for using *class-in-class-declaration*.

Second - you are packing the Fields in `def fckPackFields(self):`. This is not automatically called when you update it.

You are not calling `update` function by using `self.parent.update`.

You are using global variable for fields, what does not really suit your needs. Why not having a list inside your App-class like:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.__fields=[]
    def __set_fields(self, value):
        self.__fields=value
    def __get_fields(self):
        return self.__fields
    Fields = property(__get_fields, __set_fields)

    def __loadUI(self, event=None):
        # This function should be called at the end of __init__
        self.fieldFrame=tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.fieldFrame.pack(side="top")

    def fckPackFields(self):
        #First clean area
        [...]
        #Then add fields
        for field in self.__fields:
            # create the row, etc.
            # !!! but do it inside self.fieldFrame !!!
            [...]
```

I would prefer using grid instead of pack over here, because there I think it is easier to place a frame at a certain position, then you could just destroy `self.fieldFrame` and recreate it at the same position for placing the fields in it.

**UPDATE:**

Just checked your code again. With some simple tricks your can tweak your GUI to do what you want:

```
    def __init__(self):    
        self.fieldFrame=None   #this line has been added

    #completely reworked this function
    def grid(self):
        self.rootLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
        self.fckPackFields()
        self.BtNewField.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
        self.BtExit.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

    #Only one line changed / one added
    def fckPackFields(self):
        self.__cleanFields()    #added this line, function beyond
        if fields:
            for field in fields:
                ##create labels##
                row=tk.Frame(self.fieldFrame)    #add the row to the fieldFrame
                [...]
    #In here we destroy and recreate fieldFrame as needed
    def __cleanFields(self):
        if self.fieldFrame: 
                self.fieldFrame.destroy()
        ##FieldFrame##
        self.fieldFrame=tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.fieldFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

In `clsNewFields`:

```
    def fckAddField(self, Name, Value):
        [...]
        self.parent.fckPackFields() # instead of self.parent.update
```

**EDIT:**

Have a look at these two questions:

- [Class inside a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222251/python-2-6-class-inside-a-class)
- [Benefit of nested Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799/is-there-a-benefit-to-defining-a-class-inside-another-class-in-python)

I did not mean to point out that nested classes are to be avoided in general but I do want to focus you into the thought of *"is there a real necessity or benefit of it for my use-case"*.

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer! I did not do it exactly the way you did but you have set me on the right track. You also helped me to improve my program quite a bit. But I still have one question. If I understand you right, using class-in-class-declaration is something that I should avoid. Why is that so?

Comment: See my __EDIT:__ above